# What am I doing wrong while translating a Scala Recursion function into a Tail-Recursion function?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, tail

I am trying to take this **working** recursive function (below)...

[image: Problem A description]

```
    def cubeIt(n: Int): Int = {
        println("acc:"+acc);
        println("n: "+n);
        if(n==0){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(n>0){
            return cubeIt(n-1) + 3*(n*n) - 3*n + 1
        }
        else{
            return cubeIt(n+1) - 3*(n*n) - 3*n - 1
        }
    }
```

...and turn it into a tail-recursion function.

[image: Problem B description]

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def cubeItHelper(n: Int, acc: Int): Int = { /* Implement cubeIt as a tail recursion */
    if(n==0){
        return acc;
    }
    if(n>0){
        return cubeItHelper(n-1, acc+(3*(n*n) - 3*n + 1));
    }
    else{
        return cubeItHelper(n+1, (acc+((-3)*(n*n) - 3*n - 1)));

    }
}
/*- 
This is the main function that the users will use. 
It should call the helper with the correct initial value of acc argument. 
Just replace the ??? with the correct initial value for the acc argument.
-*/
def cubeItTail(n: Int): Int = {
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cubeItHelper(n, 0);
    }
}
```

With the above code it outputs this:

```
acc:0
n: 5
acc:61
n: 4
acc:98
n: 3
acc:117
n: 2
acc:124
n: 1
......
```

first four test lines complete correctly

```
n: -100
acc:-29701
n: -99
acc:-58808
n: -98
acc:-87327
...(goes forever)
```

These are the test statements (it's hung up on the final one):

```
assert(cubeItTail(5) == 125)
assert(cubeItTail(-5) == -125)
assert(cubeItTail(-3) == -27)
assert(cubeItTail(0) == 0)
assert( (-100 to 100).forall( x => (cubeItTail(x) == x * x * x)), "Test Passed!")
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The prints you removed were they the root cause of the problem? If so you should keep them in the question/

Comment: okay ill update it

Comment: There are two aspects of asking questions here, one is to get the answer and the other one is to leave this answer for someone with the same problem in the future to find it without having to ask again

Answer (score 1):

The print statements

`println("acc:"+acc);
 println("n: "+n);`

in the helper function were causing Jupyter Notebook to crash. They may run fully in a different environment, however. Just take note there will be **a lot** of print statements.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `cubeItTail` could be negative, in which case you would need to pass in -1 to `cubeItHelper`:

```scala
def cubeItTail(n: Int): Int = {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n > 0) {
        cubeItHelper(n, 1);
    }
    else {
        cubeItHelper(n, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is already accounted for in the helper function's if statements. I have updated the post to explain a new infinite loop I am getting

Comment: It appears to terminate for me, it does recurse quite a few times though

Comment: did it terminate as in "Test Passed!" or did it throw a timeout error? Maybe jupyter notebook for me just can't handle it?

Comment: It's possible, I think Jupyter might have strange threading that could interfere. I think "Test's Passed!" is printed when the assertion failed, so that we know which of the assertions failed. But I can see that `(-100 to 100).forall( x => (cubeItTail(x) == x * x * x))` is `true`, so your function does definitely work.

Comment: Thank you! I actually just ran it w/o the comments and it completed correctly.